# Descriptives for a specified subset of rows in r

Tags: r

I have a long format dataset with each row being another measurement (as indicated by my "timeline.compressed" variable, which has 8 possible values; see dput below).

However, now I want to check the descriptive statistics of some of my variables (i.e., x1-x3) but for each of the timepoints seperately. I've tried using the if function, but that gives me the warning that the condition has >1 in length.

Does anyone perhaps know what code I should use to be able to get summary statistics for each of the timepoints seperately?

dput for table with possible timeline values:

```
structure(c(7518L, 6178L, 6393L, 5886L, 6121L, 5977L, 7440L, 
5886L), .Dim = 8L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("5", "16", "28", 
"40", "52", "64", "79", "95")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
```

dput for example dataset

```
structure(list(nomem_encr = c(800009L, 800009L, 800012L, 800015L, 
800015L, 800015L), timeline.compressed = c(79, 95, 79, 28, 40, 
52), sel = c(4.9, NA, NA, 6.9, 6.7, NA), close_num = c(1, 0.2, 
1, 0.8, 1, 0.8), gener_sat = c(7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 5)), .Names = c("ID", 
"timeline.compressed", "x1", "x2", "x3"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr you can do, e.g. with timeline_values being your frequency table and df your data

```
data.frame(timeline.compressed = as.numeric(names(timeline_values))) %>%
  left_join(df)  %>%
  group_by(timeline.compressed) %>%
  summarize_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Okay, great! In the code you provided, I take it that I should still fill out the part where it says "timeline_values" (and also the part where it says "df"). Can I just add it like a vector, i.e., c("5", "16", "28", 
"40", "52", "64", "79", "95")?

Comment: timeline_values is your frequency table, df id your dataset, sorry, forgot to mention

Comment: If this helped you can you please accept the answer? Thanks